# how to solve my error in my script for chrome driver?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver

Hello since the last chrome update, my script which uses chrome drive does not work and shows me an error, since ChromeDriver version 110.0.5481.77 I have this error

```
Retrieving novel info...
Exception in thread Thread-1 (read_novel_info):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lncrawl\templates\browser\basic.py", line 88, in read_novel_info
  File "C:\Users\Byzz\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI138682\sources\en\w\webnovel.py", line 112, in read_novel_info_in_scraper
    raise FallbackToBrowser()
lncrawl.core.exeptions.FallbackToBrowser

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "threading.py", line 953, in run
  File "lncrawl\templates\browser\basic.py", line 95, in read_novel_info
  File "C:\Users\Byzz\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI138682\sources\en\w\webnovel.py", line 116, in read_novel_info_in_browser
    self.visit(f"{self.home_url}{path}/catalog")
  File "lncrawl\templates\browser\basic.py", line 65, in visit
  File "lncrawl\core\browser.py", line 155, in visit
  File "lncrawl\core\browser.py", line 62, in _init_browser
  File "lncrawl\webdriver\__init__.py", line 35, in create_new
  File "lncrawl\webdriver\local.py", line 115, in create_local
  File "undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 431, in __init__
  File "selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 80, in __init__
  File "selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 104, in __init__
  File "selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 286, in __init__
  File "undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 693, in start_session
  File "selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 378, in start_session
  File "selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
  File "selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:65428
from unknown error: unable to discover open pages
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        (No symbol) [0x00E537D3]
        (No symbol) [0x00DE8B81]
        (No symbol) [0x00CEB36D]
        (No symbol) [0x00D0ED6D]
        (No symbol) [0x00D070F0]
        (No symbol) [0x00D06EE1]
        (No symbol) [0x00D41ED5]
        (No symbol) [0x00D41B2C]
        (No symbol) [0x00D3B216]
        (No symbol) [0x00D10D97]
        (No symbol) [0x00D1253D]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x010CABF2+2510930]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x010F8EC1+2700065]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x010FC86C+2714828]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00F03480+645344]
        (No symbol) [0x00DF0FD2]
        (No symbol) [0x00DF6C68]
        (No symbol) [0x00DF6D4B]
        (No symbol) [0x00E00D6B]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75C100F9+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77D37BBE+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77D37B8E+238]
```

anyone have a solution?

fix the error when changing version

Comment: Which `selenium` library are you using ? As you mentioned after the update of chrome, you script is not working so make sure your selenium library is up-to-date. you can update selenium library using `pip install --upgrade selenium`  **OR** *Downgrade Chrome browser* . If you have recently updated your Chrome browser and the error started appearing after that.